# How to get all unicode characters to translate from T-SQL to DotNet

Tags: c#, t-sql

We have some `nvarchar` strings in T-SQL for which some characters are mapping into C# as `0xfdff` ([not mappable character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoderfallback?view=net-8.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN#remarks))

Here is an isolated example of one example `0x4edc` which works fine in a T-SQL string is mapped as `0xfdff` in C# - the problem is we then save this back later to the DB and it corrupts the string.

```
    [Test]
    public void DotNetUnicodeToSqlServerTest()
    {
        var unmappableCharacter = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(new byte[] { 0x4e, 0xdc });
        var con = new SqlConnection(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=unicode_test;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        con.Open();
        var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = $"SELECT unicode(N'{unmappableCharacter}')";
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();
        var unicode = reader.GetInt32(0);
        // Fails to map to a unicode character, so it's replaced with the replacement character
        Assert.That(unicode, Is.EqualTo(0xfffd));
    }
    
    [Test]
    public void SqlServerToDotNetTest()
    {
        var con = new SqlConnection(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=unicode_test;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        con.Open();
        var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = $"SELECT convert(nvarchar(10), 0x4edc), unicode(convert(nvarchar(10), 0x4edc))";
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();
        var unmappableCharacter = reader.GetSqlString(0).Value;
        // Fails to map to a unicode character, so it's replaced with the replacement character
        Assert.That(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(unmappableCharacter), Is.EqualTo(new byte[] { 0xfd, 0xff }));
        var unicode = reader.GetInt32(1);
        // T-SQL is happy to process the unmappable character
        Assert.That(unicode, Is.EqualTo(0xdc4e));
    }
```

I am not sure what is causing this. I tested it across the whole range of `0x0000-0xffff` and it turns out that **2,050** of these do not map (the rest are fine). For example, running the same code with `0x3fe0` works fine.

Can someone explain what it going on and if there is something that I need to do to get all the characters to map properly.

(Using `SQL Server 2019`, `C#6`, Collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` if that helps)

**Please note** that this is not saving data to any table, so I do not believe the collation is the problem directly. Also the string is fine to modify and use within T-SQL, it's only when it is mapped into C# that it breaks for reasons I do not understand.

My code to show the ranges that *do not* map into C# (are replaced with `0xfdff`)

```
    [Test]
    public void UnicodeTranslationTest()
    {
        var con = new SqlConnection(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=unicode_test;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        con.Open();

        var startOfBrokenRange = default(string);

        for (var i = 0; i < ushort.MaxValue; i++)
        {
            var bytes = new byte[2];
            bytes[0] = (byte)(i >> 8);  
            bytes[1] = (byte)i;  

            var original = "0x" + bytes[0].ToString("X2") + bytes[1].ToString("X2");

            string stringInDotNet;
            using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = $"SELECT 1 id, convert(nchar(1), {original}) text";
                using var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                reader.Read();
                stringInDotNet = (string)reader[1];
            }

            var translated = "0x" + string.Join("", Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(stringInDotNet).Select(b => b.ToString("x2"))).ToUpper();
            if (translated != original)
            {
                startOfBrokenRange ??= original;
            }
            else
            {
                if (startOfBrokenRange == null) continue;
                Console.WriteLine(startOfBrokenRange + "-" + original);
                startOfBrokenRange = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Produces a list or ranges with a similar pattern:

```
0x00D8-0x00E0
0x01D8-0x01E0
0x02D8-0x02E0
0x03D8-0x03E0
0x04D8-0x04E0
0x05D8-0x05E0
0x06D8-0x06E0
0x07D8-0x07E0
<<SNIP>>
```

Maybe there is a clue here?

Further edit - in trying to figure out the difference between the SQL strings and C# strings, I tried some other encodings in C# and it seems the the Latin1 encoding does appear to handle the example `0x4edc` character as I would "expect" (given my confusion!)

```
    [Test]
    public void DotNetCanSupportProblemStringWithLatin1()
    {
        var unmappableCharacter = Encoding.Latin1.GetString(new byte[] { 0x4e, 0xdc });
        var hex = "0x" + string.Join("", Encoding.Latin1.GetBytes(unmappableCharacter).Select(b => b.ToString("x2")));
        Assert.That(hex, Is.EqualTo("0x4edc"));
    }


    [Test]
    public void DotNetCanSupportProblemStringWithDefaultUTF8()
    {
        var unmappableCharacter = Encoding.Default.GetString(new byte[] { 0x4e, 0xdc });
        var hex = "0x" + string.Join("", Encoding.Default.GetBytes(unmappableCharacter).Select(b => b.ToString("x2")));
        Assert.That(hex, Is.EqualTo("0x4eefbfbd"));
    }
```

Comment: Ha. I notice I am immediately marked down for this question. What has happened to Stack Overflow these days? Sad really.

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort" And it was not /me who did do the downvote!

Comment: Does it not? I've spent hours on this and provided a clear description and a reproducible example. What more do people want?

Comment: The answer is probably in (I  am not sure, because TL/DR): https://stackoverflow.com/a/32859598/724039   Which describe the _historical_ mess with ANSI/UTF8/UTF16/UCS2.  Long story, but you should have chosen another collation than `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`, when you need to store such characters.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to read/understand. Looks like I'm going to need a stiff coffee first. It's a pretty complicated and dry subject - was hoping for a silver bullet from someone with a lot more braincells than me :) - yeah that's just the default collation... will be tricky to change that... it does work fine being manipulated/modified inside sql though... only when it's exported to C# does it get corrupted

Comment: I tried to create a DBFIDDLE, which shows more info, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/N1hEhdZN  , and for the rest I try  to say away from this subject  (Because I do not know enough of the deeper/underlying stuff..... )

Comment: Sadly, I don't think this is the solution... the example I provided doesn't save the data. I did try making a test db with a UTF8 collation and connecting to that in the same example, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Thank - I do not believe collation can be specified in [connection string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlConnection_ConnectionString)?

Comment: `nchar(1)` is one 16-bit UTF-16 character. It is not enough to represent many Unicode codepoints. If you have a codepoint in that nvarchar column of yours that requires more than one UTF-16 character, and you take only the first one, what you are left with is a disconnected surrogate which does not represent a character on its own, [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74495233/11683).

Comment: `Maybe there is a clue here?` - yes, they are [surrogates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U+D800_to_U+DFFF_(surrogates)).

Comment: I think @Gseg is correct. Adding this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks) for clarification from microsoft.

Comment: OK thanks @GSerg ... I would say that the nchar(1) is a red-herring though... nchar(larger) or nvarchar(some sufficiently large number) still produces the same problem when mapping to DotNet.... the answer to this question perhaps that it's not possible. I really need to deal with strings sadly - if I pass byte arrays (cast to varbinary then map to byte[]), it works as one would expect.

Comment: @Kram The 1 is not important per se, any number that splits a surrogate pair will break it. If you read the string as a string in full, it won't happen.

Comment: @GSerg I am reading it in full, and it's totally fine in sql (updated the test above) - but, seems that some of the characters just aren't getting mapped into dotnet default strings (which are utf-16 - correction!)

Comment: @Kram Dotnet strings are UTF-16. There are no non-UTF-16 strings in dotnet. `nvarchar` is UTF-16 too.

Comment: OK, thanks @GSerg - the fact remains I am reading this in full and it is fine in sql but not in c# - if you can see how I should modify my tests to work properly then I'd be very happy and would willingly accept the answer to my question :)

Comment: In all your code samples you are truncating the string. Also, for the sake of it, what happens when you use `reader.GetString()` instead of the case?

Comment: I am not truncating the string. I changed it from nchar(1) and simplified the tests. It still fails. `reader.GetString(0)` produces the same result as `reader.GetSqlString(0).Value`

Comment: All your code samples generate a standalone surrogate to begin with. You have not shown code that reads a table column in full and demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I do not want to use a table for this and that is not relevant to the question - I can promise you that if I store this nvarchar in a table and load it again, it works fine in SQL - it's only when mapped to c# (and then stored back into the table). I have added some more code that shows (I think) that the problem is more around the c# strings (apologies for my lack of understanding though!)

Comment: The [Latin1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) codepage does not have a concept of surrogates, so your `0x4e, 0xdc` are two separate characters `NÜ`. In UTF-16 those bytes are an [unpaired surrogate character](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+DC4E), which is invalid like the [aforementioned Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U+D800_to_U+DFFF_(surrogates)) tells you. It "works fine" in SQL because the SQL Server happens to not care, and C# happens to care. For the lack of understanding please see https://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html.

Comment: Thanks.... so given this I think you're saying there is no way to do what I want, at least using standard types and libraries (nvarchar, c# strings and sqlclient), as this difference in "caring" in SQL vs .net is where the translation/mapping breaks down?

Comment: It's not clear [why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640) you want that in the first place. The point where it fails though is when .NET asks the [Unicode encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049478/net-string-object-and-invalid-unicode-code-points#comment44685541_27084836) to create the string from the bytes received from the SQL Server. If you were to construct this invalid string manually, it would [remain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27074904/11683) the way you constructed it.

Comment: I have strings that are valid in SQL server and don't translate/are corrupted when loading into C# hence this question, which I have clearly tried to research to the best of my knowledge, with reproducible steps. It seems that, in very long-winded way, with clearly some confusion, that the answer appears to be "No you cannot load all valid SQL string in C# as SQL allows strings that cannot be represented in C#" for some of the reasons linked. A suppose a truly authoritative answer would also include some of the (perhaps legacy) reasons for SQL's handling of strings and why it differs.

Comment: (I'll wait a bit longer in case someone comes along with a Eureka moment, and re-read some of these links, but otherwise I'll answer this question myself, trying to cite some of these links, if it's not already answered)

Comment: They are not valid strings in SQL Server either. It's just that SQL Server does not bother to validate them.

Comment: SQL-Server uses UCS-2 with N-chars.  This is *not* the full Unicode/UTF-16 actually. That means: 2 bytes for each character. Although that's a lot, there are so many characters out there in the world, that this is not enough. So there are characters telling: "Hey, this is a magic code. The next code is taken from another set" (UTF-8 does the same trick up to 4 bytes per char). This allows for letters in any language, emojis and all this fancy stuff. Your problem occurs *between* SQL-Server and dotnet. You might change to passing XML (will use implicit encoding), base64 on both ends or binary.